# Getting the Queue name from within the MDB

Tags: jms, websphere

I have 2 Websphere application Server(WAS) applications, one sending a message and the other reading and processing it . I need the queue name to be known in the reading application for my downstream processing. 
I am trying to get the queue name (in the reading application) by using the following code . But however I get NullPointerException since the `getJMSDestination` is returning `null`.

```
Queue queue = (Queue)message.getJMSDestination();
logger.info("Queue ID: "+queue.getQueueName());
```

Note that the queue name is set via the destination object in the sending application.
Is there any other parameters that I am missing to set in the sending application ?

Comment: You need the name of the queue you got the message from or the name of the queue the sender has sent it to (they could be different)

Comment: I  need the name of the queue the second MDB application got the message from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message should have the destination stored in its `JMSDestination` property, you can try fetch that instead of using `getJMSDestination()`

Comment: I used something like this :                                        logger.info("Dest from property: "+   message.getObjectProperty(MQConstants.MQ_JMS_DESTINATION));       But null is returned

Comment: I am using Websphere MQ 7.0

Comment: `MQConstants.MQ_JMS_DESTINATION` is `JMSDestination`, You can try reading the JMS destination from the RFH2 header with `MQConstants.RFH2_JMS_DESTINATION`

Comment: Unfortunately the following statement too returned null:             logger.info("Dest from RFH    : "+
               message.getObjectProperty(MQConstants.RFH2_JMS_DESTINATION));

Comment: Sorry but I don't have any more idea, hopefully someone else will be able to help

Answer (score 0):

I've using Spring with ActiveMQ, and this appears to work for me:

```
    public void processMessage( Message msg )
    {
       // Get the queue name from the supplied Message.
       String sourceQueueName = "UNKNOWN";
       try
       {
           ActiveMQDestination sourceQueue = (ActiveMQDestination) msg.getJMSDestination();
           sourceQueueName = sourceQueue.getPhysicalName();
       }
       catch ( JMSException e )
       {
           LOGGER.error( "Cannot get JMSDestination from Message: " + msg, e );
       }
       ....
```

Does WAS have a Queue object you can cast to that exposes similar methods?

Comment: Yes WAS does have a Queue object which can be used. I am using something like this Queue queue = (Queue)message.getJMSDestination(); logger.info("Queue ID : "+queue.getQueueName()); However the queue object is null. Any clue why the destination would be passed as null by the sending application